# What's the difference between "identity" and "formula"?

Tags: terminology

For example is $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ an "identity" or "formula"?

If they're different, please give an example of an identity that isn't a formula and an example of a formula that isn't an identity.

Comment: Have you tried searching the Wikipedia pages for these terms?

Answer (score 1):

The term *formula* has a wider scope than *identity*. Roughly speaking, the term *identity* is used when you are implicitly adding universal quantifiers in the front. Thus 
$$
a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)
$$
is an identity since it holds for all $a$ and $b$. The term *formula* can be used to define a function or a sequence. For instance, you could say "let $u_n$ be the sequence defined by the formulas $u_0 = 2$ and $u_{n+1}= 1 +u_n^2$".

That being said, both terms also have a precise definition in logic. I let you read this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_formula) for more detials.

Answer (score 0):

A formula always has 2 or more variables and is used to find an unknown quantity while value of variables from an identity cannot be find out as they infinite solutions.ex of formula can be like W=mg where we have one value and use that to find the other while a plus b whole squared equals a squared plus b squared plus 2ab is an identity if u have value of a you can't find value of b.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).